# how to get the object reference of a class which has a label control inside it from that label?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class which has a Label field. Now i want to get the reference of that class from that label. How can i do that?
Here is what i have.

```
public class Abc
{
    Label l;
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void btnins_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Abc ob=new Abc();
       ob.l=new new Label();
       l.Text="Right Click Me";
       l.ContextMenuStrip = cntxtdelmnu;
    }


    private void cntxtdelnode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Label lbl= (Label)cntxtdelmnu.SourceControl;

       //Here I have to get the reference of ob using lbl.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, basically. There could be *multiple* objects which have references to that label - or none at all. You can't get a "backwards" reference. You could potentially store a reference in the `Tag` property:

```
Abc ob=new Abc();
ob.l= new Label();
ob.l.Text="Right Click Me";
ob.l.ContextMenuStrip = cntxtdelmnu;
ob.l.Tag = ob;
```

Or using an *object initializer*:

```
Abc ob = new Abc();
ob.l = new Label { Text = "Right Click Me", ContextMenuStrip = cntxtdelmnu, Tag = ob };
```

I would *try* to avoid needing that though. It's not clear from the question why you want it, but there may be better approaches. (I really hope those aren't your real names, too...)

Comment: Thanks... for reply
My problem is solved by using Tag property.
And yes those were not the real name.
Actually i am developing an application in which i faced this problem.
Well it is solved now.